# Gps location icon is not off

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

In my app, I implemented Cllocation manager to use current user location & it works fine. But when the app enter in background or terminate,the GPS location icon is hide automatically in ipod. When i try same with Iphone, the icon is not hide.

So, i can't find any solution for it. Help me!!

My code is as follow:

AppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
     self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

if(locationManager == nil)

        locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy= kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter= 5;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}


-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    self.userLocation=newLocation;

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

Map.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [APPDELEGATE.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.map.delegate = self;

    [self.map setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}
```

if i manually on location service for my app in ipod,when the app is closed, it not shown location icon. But when i try for the same in iphone,it shows location icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really want is:

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

directly afterward, if you want the manager to wake up on a significant location change, then call:

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

The opposite applies to go back to continuous updating:

```
[self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationchanges];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Note: When in Significant Location Change mode, the icon in status bar will still show the same as when updating location continuous. This is not an issue for concern as in the conservative mode it is still shutting the location services down when unneeded.
The ipod does not support startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. That is why the indicator behaves differently on the two devices.

You should consider that, as you have it implemented, you are using whatever the first event reports for location out of the manager. This can often be stale, cached, old or very likely horribly inaccurate. It is standard practice to use a bit of testing and give a chance for more suitable location info as needed for your purpose.

See [my handler](https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler) on Github for more help as you work with location services.

Answer (score 1):

finally i solved this problem like below.

Instead of

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

In appdelegate

i write,

```
[self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```